# Имя интернет сети с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, сеть, c++17

Как узнать имя интернет сети к которой подключен комп. Подключен ли интернет проверяю так:

```
#include <wininet.h>
typedef BOOL(WINAPI* INETCHECKPROC) (LPDWORD lpdwFlags, DWORD dwReserved);
bool GetStatusConnect()
{
    bool bRetVal;
    HINSTANCE hLib = NULL;
    INETCHECKPROC pfnInternetGetConnectedState;
    hLib = LoadLibrary("wininet.dll");
    if (!hLib)
        return 0;
    pfnInternetGetConnectedState = (INETCHECKPROC)GetProcAddress(hLib, "InternetGetConnectedState");
    if (!pfnInternetGetConnectedState)
        return false;
    DWORD lpdwFlags;
    bRetVal = pfnInternetGetConnectedState(&lpdwFlags, 0) != 0;
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
    return bRetVal;
}
```

Вот только как узнать имя сети?

Comment: Что такое "имя интернет сети" в вашем понимании, приведите пример?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385374(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Kromster, имя вай-фай например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так можно получить названия адаптера и соответствующего сетевого подключения:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

#include <Netlistmgr.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")
// Link with Iphlpapi.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

#define WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE 15000
#define MAX_TRIES 3

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

/********************************************************************************/

//Получает информацию о соединении по GUID адаптера
NLM_CONNECTIVITY GetAdapterConnectivity(LPCWSTR adapter){

    INetworkListManager *pNetworkListManager = NULL; 
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NetworkListManager, NULL,
            CLSCTX_ALL, IID_INetworkListManager,
            (LPVOID *)&pNetworkListManager);
    if(FAILED(hr)){ 
        printf("CoCreateInstance failed: 0x%x\n",(UINT)hr);
        return (NLM_CONNECTIVITY)0; 
    }

    IEnumNetworkConnections* pEnum = NULL;
    hr = pNetworkListManager->GetNetworkConnections(&pEnum);
    if(FAILED(hr)){ 
        pNetworkListManager->Release();
        printf("GetNetworkConnections failed: 0x%x\n",(UINT)hr);
        return (NLM_CONNECTIVITY)0; 
    }

    const int NUM_CONNECTION = 10;
    INetworkConnection* pNetworkConnections[NUM_CONNECTION];
    ULONG cFetched = 0;
    BOOL  bDone = FALSE;
    GUID guid;
    NLM_CONNECTIVITY nlmc=(NLM_CONNECTIVITY)0;

    while (!bDone)
    {
        hr = pEnum->Next(NUM_CONNECTION, pNetworkConnections, &cFetched);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (cFetched > 0))
        {
            for (ULONG i = 0; i < cFetched; i++)
            {
                pNetworkConnections[i]->GetAdapterId(&guid);

                OLECHAR* guidString;
                StringFromCLSID(guid, &guidString);             
                if(wcscmp(adapter,guidString) == 0){
                    pNetworkConnections[i]->GetConnectivity(&nlmc);
                }
                // ensure memory is freed
                ::CoTaskMemFree(guidString);
                pNetworkConnections[i]->Release();  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bDone = TRUE;
        }
    }

    pEnum->Release();
    pNetworkListManager->Release();
    return nlmc;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{               
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    CoInitialize(NULL); 

    /* Declare and initialize variables */

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    unsigned int i = 0;

    // Set the flags to pass to GetAdaptersAddresses
    ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX;

    // default to unspecified address family (both)
    ULONG family = AF_UNSPEC;

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = NULL;
    ULONG outBufLen = 0;
    ULONG Iterations = 0;

    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = NULL;
    PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pUnicast = NULL;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ANYCAST_ADDRESS pAnycast = NULL;
    PIP_ADAPTER_MULTICAST_ADDRESS pMulticast = NULL;
    IP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS *pDnServer = NULL;
    IP_ADAPTER_PREFIX *pPrefix = NULL;

    // Allocate a 15 KB buffer to start with.
    outBufLen = WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE;

    do {

        pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *) MALLOC(outBufLen);
        if (pAddresses == NULL) {
            printf ("Memory allocation failed for IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES struct\n");
            goto End;
        }

        dwRetVal =
            GetAdaptersAddresses(family, flags, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen);

        if (dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
            FREE(pAddresses);
            pAddresses = NULL;
        } else {
            break;
        }

        Iterations++;

    } while ((dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) && (Iterations < MAX_TRIES));

    if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
        // If successful, output some information from the data we received
        wprintf(L"*** Network connections ***\n\n");
        pCurrAddresses = pAddresses;
        while (pCurrAddresses) {            

            WCHAR* adapter = NULL;
            int c = strlen(pCurrAddresses->AdapterName);
            adapter = (WCHAR*)MALLOC((c+1) * 2);
            ZeroMemory(adapter,(c+1) * 2);
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,pCurrAddresses->AdapterName,c,adapter,c);
            //wprintf(L"\tGUID: %s\n", adapter);    
            NLM_CONNECTIVITY nlmc = GetAdapterConnectivity(adapter);
            if(nlmc != NLM_CONNECTIVITY_DISCONNECTED){
                wprintf(L"Adapter: %s\n", pCurrAddresses->Description);
                wprintf(L"Network: %s\n", pCurrAddresses->FriendlyName);    
                wprintf(L"Connected to:", (UINT)nlmc);  
                if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_LOCALNETWORK) wprintf(L" IPv4 LAN;");
                if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET) wprintf(L" IPv4 Internet;");
                if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_LOCALNETWORK) wprintf(L" IPv6 LAN;");
                if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_INTERNET) wprintf(L" IPv6 Internet");
                wprintf(L"\n\n");
            }
            FREE(adapter);                  

            pCurrAddresses = pCurrAddresses->Next;
        }
    } else {
        printf("Call to GetAdaptersAddresses failed with error: %d\n",
               dwRetVal);
        if (dwRetVal == ERROR_NO_DATA)
            printf("\tNo addresses were found for the requested parameters\n");
        else {

            if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
                    NULL, dwRetVal, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),   
                    // Default language
                    (LPTSTR) & lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL)) {
                printf("\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
                LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
                if (pAddresses)
                    FREE(pAddresses);
               goto End;
            }
        }
    }

    if (pAddresses) {
        FREE(pAddresses);
    }

    End:
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

А так - имя сети:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

#include <Netlistmgr.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

/********************************************************************************/

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{               
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    CoInitialize(NULL); 

    INetworkListManager *pNetworkListManager = NULL; 
    IEnumNetworkConnections* pEnum = NULL;

    //инициализация Network List Manager API
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NetworkListManager, NULL,
            CLSCTX_ALL, IID_INetworkListManager,
            (LPVOID *)&pNetworkListManager);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ 
        printf("CoCreateInstance failed: 0x%x\n",(UINT)hr);
        goto End;
    }

    hr = pNetworkListManager->GetNetworkConnections(&pEnum); //получаем сетевые подключения
    if(FAILED(hr)){         
        printf("GetNetworkConnections failed: 0x%x\n",(UINT)hr);
        goto End;
    }

    wprintf(L"*** Networks *** \n\n");

    const int NUM_CONNECTION = 10;
    INetworkConnection* pNetworkConnections[NUM_CONNECTION];
    ULONG cFetched = 0;
    BOOL  bDone = FALSE;    
    NLM_CONNECTIVITY nlmc;
    INetwork* pNetwork = NULL;
    BSTR name;

    while (!bDone)
    {
        hr = pEnum->Next(NUM_CONNECTION, pNetworkConnections, &cFetched);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (cFetched > 0))
        {
            for (ULONG i = 0; i < cFetched; i++)
            {
                nlmc=(NLM_CONNECTIVITY)0;
                name = NULL;                

                hr = pNetworkConnections[i]->GetNetwork(&pNetwork); //получаем сеть, соответствующую подключению
                if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
                    hr = pNetwork->GetName(&name); //получаем имя сети
                    if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && name != NULL){
                        wprintf(L"%s ",name);                       

                        pNetworkConnections[i]->GetConnectivity(&nlmc);
                        if(nlmc != 0) wprintf(L"- connected to:");                      

                        if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_LOCALNETWORK) wprintf(L" IPv4 LAN;");
                        if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET) wprintf(L" IPv4 Internet;");
                        if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_LOCALNETWORK) wprintf(L" IPv6 LAN;");
                        if (nlmc & NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_INTERNET) wprintf(L" IPv6 Internet");
                        wprintf(L"\n");
                    }
                    pNetwork->Release();
                }   
                // ensure memory is freed                
                pNetworkConnections[i]->Release();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bDone = TRUE;
        }
    }

    End:
    if(pEnum!=NULL)pEnum->Release();
    if(pNetworkListManager!=NULL)pNetworkListManager->Release();    

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Ссылки:**

[Network Awareness in Windows Vista and Windows 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee264321(v=vs.85))

[GetAdaptersAddresses function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: этот код выдает имя адаптера, а мне нужно имя самой сети

Comment: @abc123 Обновил ответ